# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined variable masterRow is undefined in KendoUI Grid detailInit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I posted a question the other and it got answered,[my answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906304/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-the-selected-row-from-the-detailinit-then-collapse-the-d/34921913#34921913), which i was thankful for, I modified my code to match the other members code that he set up in the Telerik Dojo [Heres a dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UgIDi/3)
Everything is goin well up until I reach

`var masterRow = masterGrid.dataSource.get(groupID);`

thats where I am getting it as undefined and I am not sure why...my full code is

```
function onSelectedRowClick(e) {
    var catalogGrid = $("#CatalogGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedID = catalogGrid.dataItem(catalogGrid.select());
    var theID = selectedID.globalGroupID;
    myID = theID;
    groupID = myID;
}

var myID;

// #region Catalog Grid

var groupID;

function TheCatalogGrid(catalogData) {
    $("#CatalogGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: catalogData
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "globalGroupID",
            }
        },

        columns: [
           { field: "globalGroupLevel", title: "globalGroupLevel", hidden: true },
           { field: "globalGroupName", title: "Group Name", width:350 },
           { field: "isRequired", title: "*", width:20 },
           { field: "optionName", title: "Option Name" },
           { title: "Description" },
           { title: "Price" }
        ],

        change: function (e) {
            onSelectedRowClick();
        },
        scrollable: true,
        pageable: false,
        selectable: "row",
        height: 500,
        dataBound: function (e) {
            var data = this.dataSource.data();
            $.each(data, function (i, row) {
                if (row.get("globalGroupLevel") == 0) {
                    var element = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ');
                    element.addClass("colored-row");
                }
            });
        },
        detailInit: detailInit,
        detailExpand: function(e){
            groupID = this.dataItem(e.masterRow).get("globalGroupID");
        },
    });
}
function detailInit(e) {
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: URLParams.GetTheGlobalGroupOptions + "?id=" + groupID
            },
        },
        scrollable: false,
        selectable: "row",
        filter: { field: "GlobalGroupID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.globalGroupID },
        change: function (e) {
            // get detail row
            var detailRow = this.dataItem(this.select());
            var optionName = detailRow.get("OptionName") // Change this stuff to populate into the correct columns

            // get master row
            var masterGrid = $("#CatalogGrid").getKendoGrid();
            var masterRow = masterGrid.dataSource.get(groupID);

            // set 'Option Name' value to master row 'optionName' field
            masterRow.set("optionName", optionName);

        },
        columns: [
            { field: "OptionName", title: "Option Name" },
            { field: "OptionDescription", title: "Description" },
            { field: "OptionPriceComment", title: "Price" }
        ]
    });
}
```

any idea on why its coming as undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic was good... but for some reason, the `dataSource.get` doesn't seems to search correctly for the specified `groupID`.  You can use the `grid.dataItem` as a work around solution.

First, make sure that the data provided to the main grid has an `optionName` property as defined in the dataSource columns (Not sure if it really matters but I added it to your [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ThisGuySays/OZEtA) just to make sure).

The second thing to change is your `detailInit` function.  The function will receive the `e.masterRow` as parameter so you won't have to search in the master grid to get the linked masterRow.  However, make sure the `e` variable from the detailInit doesn't conflict with the `e` variable of the change function by renaming one of them or by keeping a reference like I did in the following example:

```
function detailInit(e) {
    var masterRow = e.masterRow; //Keep a reference to your masterRow to avoid conflict with change... you could also use a different name
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: [{ OptionName: "Delivery"}, {OptionName: "PickUp"}],
        scrollable: false,
        selectable: "row",
        filter: { field: "globalGroupID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.globalGroupID },
        change: function (e) {
            var detailRow = this.dataItem(this.select());
            var optionName = detailRow.get("OptionName") // Change this stuff to populate into the correct columns

            //Use the masterRow directly to get the dataItem from the master grid
            $("#grid").getKendoGrid().dataItem(masterRow).set("optionName", optionName);
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "OptionName", title: "Option Name" },
            { field: "OptionDescription", title: "Description" },
            { field: "OptionPriceComment", title: "Price" }
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: I just tested this is my environment and it works perfectly, thank you so much!
You know your Kendo very well, is there a book on Kendo like there is with the Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX? or know of any in depth KendoUI books/tutorials?

Comment: I'm more a self-learning person... I spent the last 2 years working with the grid and this is how I learned it.  SO and Telerik's forum are probably the best resources when you have a specific question.

Comment: I've only been using Kendo for a couple months now, but I know UI for ASP.NET AJAX pretty well. But both frameworks are entirely different. Thanks for all your help and direction, I do appreciate it and have learned a couple things from what you have done.